# How do I use the send_data method in Rails for my entire index view and not just the first page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, will-paginate

I would like to be able to download my index data from my Order table in csv format. I have been able to implement this functionality with the following code:

```
orders controller:

class OrdersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_order, only: [:edit, :destroy, :update, :show]

    def index
        @orders = Order.all.order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
        # to allow csv and xls formats to be downloaded
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html 
            format.csv { send_data @orders.to_csv }
            format.xls { send_data @orders.to_csv(col_sep: "\t") } # tab separate to work with Excel
        end
    end
```

Order model:

```
def self.to_csv(options = {}) 
        CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
            csv << column_names
            all.each do |order|
                csv << order.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
            end
        end
    end
```

This, however, only lets me download the first 20 entries in the Order table because of the pagination I have. I thought the following code would fix it, but it doesn't change anything:

```
def index
        @orders = Order.all
        # to allow csv and xls formats to be downloaded
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { @orders.order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20) }
            format.csv { send_data @orders.to_csv }
            format.xls { send_data @orders.to_csv(col_sep: "\t") } # tab separate to work with Excel
        end
    end

app/views/orders/index.html.erb:43:in `_app_views_orders_index_html_erb___1955221700531553779_70231785858000'
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-11-28 01:19:56 +0100
Processing by OrdersController#index as HTML
  Rendering orders/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Order Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?  [["LIMIT", 10], ["OFFSET", 0]]
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "orders"
  Rendered orders/index.html.erb within layouts/application (44.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 216ms (Views: 203.2ms | ActiveRecord: 6.4ms)


Started GET "/orders.csv" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-11-28 01:20:03 +0100
Processing by OrdersController#index as CSV
  Order Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?  [["LIMIT", 10], ["OFFSET", 0]]
  Rendering text template
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Sent data  (4.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 15ms (Views: 4.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
```

Any ideas of how to keep the pagination but be able to download all entries in the Order table?

Comment: Wait. You don't want pagination? How about removing `.paginate`, then?

Comment: No, I do want pagination on my index view. I just want to be able to download all enteries in the Order table. At the moment I can only download the first 20 because of pagination (which I want to keep)

Comment: as @jvillian suggested, but you already set `@orders = Order.all` and still got pagnated result is weird. @orders was tampered somewhere else, like `before_action`?

Comment: Can you show your console log? I wonder if you're not using the `.csv` format and instead ending up in the `.html` format?

Comment: Okay, the code I mentioned I tried actually throws an error. I've added the console log of the original code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might be as simple as moving the `.paginate` call into a `format.html { ... }` block

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_order, only: [:edit, :destroy, :update, :show]

    def index
        orders = Order.all.order("created_at DESC")

        # to allow csv and xls formats to be downloaded
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html do 
                @orders = orders.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
            end
            format.csv { send_data orders.to_csv }
            format.xls { send_data orders.to_csv(col_sep: "\t") } # tab separate to work with Excel
        end
    end

    ...
end
```

You **MAY** have to add a `render :index`inside the format.html block. I have not been able to test this code currently.

Comment: I just spotted another comment in your post; You've tried something similar.. I have tried this approach as shown in my answer once, with success.. If it is not working, let me know, i will fire up a new rails app, and give it a go for you! :)

Comment: This works! Thanks a lot for your help - much appreciated!